# Get specific number in line

Tags: shell

I have this file

```
    123 My name is Lorry I'm 29 years old 10000 45
    148 Name - Dan 20000 18
    895 My name is John Lazaro I like tennis 30000 63
```

And I want to print only last numbers in a line

```
45
18
63
```

Is it possible to do that?

UPDATE:
Now I want to print

```
10000
20000
30000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `awk` to print last filed:

```
awk '{ print $NF }' file
```

and for printing field next to the last:

```
awk '{ print $(NF - 1) }' file
```

Answer (score 4):

In your case, the last (space-separated) word happens to be a number. If that's always the case, then your problem can be reduced to printing the last word like:

```
awk 'NF {print $NF}'
```

or

```
sed 's/.* //'
```

For the one before last:

```
awk 'NF >= 2 {print $(NF-1)}'
```

If you want to print the last word iif it's a positive decimal integer number then that becomes:

```
awk '$NF ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $NF}'
```

(replace `$NF` with `$(NF-1)` for the one before last).

If you want to print rightmost sequence of decimal digits in every line, then:

```
sed -n 's/^/./;s/.*[^0-9]\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p'
```

For the one before last:

```
sed -n 's/^/./;s/.*[^0-9]\([0-9]\{1,\}\)[^0-9].*[0-9].*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone need my updated output just type this

```
awk '{print $(NF-1)}' file.txt
```